# Adding Daily Dates to a Table With a Date Range

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to take data from a table that includes a date range, and insert into a new table that adds a new row for every day in the date range and a column with the daily date in it.  See below for before and after results.

[image]

Comment: There are a few ways to tackle this, but the most common ways would be to either use a calendar table (if you don't already have one, you can search for "calendar table sql server" and find many examples to help you create one - these can be useful for other date-related queries as well) OR you can dynamically generate the dates between two dates by using a combination of `DATEDIFF(DAY, startdate, enddate` and a numbers table (if you don't have one, you can use standard approaches such as master..spt_values or row_number() with sys.objects or generating your own).\

Comment: I do have a calendar table but it seems that I would want to do some sort of join to my starting table but I don't have anything to join on.  The calendar table only has 1 column called "CalendarDate".

Comment: You join on the date. So for example, `FROM MyTable JOIN Calendar ON Calendar.CalenderDate >= MyTable.StartDate AND Calendar.CalendarDate <= MyTable.EndDate`

Comment: That works great.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    Declare @Tab Table(Deal int,Type varchar(10),person Varchar(10), StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME)

    Insert into @Tab
    Select 12345,'Gas','Bob','2019/1/1','2019/1/5' Union All
    Select 44444,'Oil','Sue','2019/1/1','2019/1/3'


    ;WITH cte AS
    (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1 AS [Incrementor]
      FROM   [master].[sys].[columns] sc1
      CROSS JOIN [master].[sys].[columns] sc2
    )


    SELECT t.*,DATEADD(DAY, cte.[Incrementor], t.StartDate) As [Date]
    FROM   cte
    CROSS JOIN @Tab t
    WHERE  DATEADD(DAY, cte.[Incrementor], t.StartDate) <= t.EndDate
    Order by t.Deal
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  This does return the proper results, the only issue is the insert statement must be made for each deal which is going to be burdensome because there are quite a few deals in the database and they change every day.

Comment: I edited that query to use a select statement to insert rows into @tab.  It seems to work except that its limiting the number of rows per deal to 1936 so not all of the dates are returned.  I'm not sure if that's a limitation of the query or the database I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
;WITH rs AS (
    SELECT t.Deal,t.StartDate AS [Date] FROM @Table t 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT rs.Deal,DATEADD(DAY,1,rs.[Date]) AS [Date]
    FROM rs
    INNER JOIN @Table t ON t.Deal = rs.Deal
    WHERE t.EndDate > rs.[Date]
)
SELECT t.Deal,t.StartDate,t.EndDate,rs.[Date]
FROM @Table t
INNER JOIN rs on rs.Deal = t.Deal
ORDER BY rs.Deal,rs.[Date]
;
```